# How do I pivot a table with multiple occurrences for every value? (T-Sql)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, pivot

I have tables corresponding to the results of a survey, including users, questions and answers:

User table:

| ID_USER | USER |
| --- | --- |
| IdForUser1 | USER1 |
| IdForUser2 | USER2 |
| IdForUser-N | USER-N |

Questions table:

| ID_QUESTION | QUESTION | ID_SURVEY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Question1 | 2 |
| 2 | Question2 | 2 |

Answers table:

| ID_ANSWER | ID_QUESTION | ANSWER | USER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | AnswerToQuestion1 | IdForUser1 |
| 2 | 2 | AnswerToQuestion2 | IdForUser1 |
| 3 | 1 | AnswerToQuestion1 | IdForUser2 |

I need to generate a result like the following:

| USER | QUESTION1 | QUESTION2 | QUESTION-N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USER1 | AnswerToQuestion1 | AnswerToQuestion2 | AnswerToQuestion-N |
| USER2 | AnswerToQuestion1 | AnswerToQuestion2 | AnswerToQuestion-N |
| USER-N | AnswerToQuestion1 | AnswerToQuestion2 | AnswerToQuestion-N |

As you can see, there can be many occurrences for the same question in the answers table, so I have only been able to make queries where I get the same question on multiple rows.

What do I do for this case? I have tried with pivoting. I'm using T-SQL.

Comment: I'm guessing you always want just `QUESTION1` and `QUESTION2`, shouldn't you have 2 answer columns? If you want a dynamic number of columns some tricky dynamic TSQL will be needed.

Comment: presumably `USER` is a candidate key for the User Table?

Comment: *I have tried with pivoting but ...* - can you please share your current code and describe what's wrong with it. Currently there's nothing more to answer than "just pivot it". Also it looks like the query requires answers table only, because the output doesn't contain any information absent in this table.

Comment: This is very unclear. What do you mean, "so"? What does the part after the "so" have to do with the part before the so? What case is "this case" and what does it have to do with what you wrote before? Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Users
CREATE TABLE #Users (ID_User INT,[User] VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #Users(ID_User,[User])
VALUES
( 1,'User1'),
( 2,'User2'),
( 3,'User3')

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Questions
CREATE TABLE #Questions (ID_QuestionID INT,Question VARCHAR(10),ID_Survey INT)
INSERT INTO #Questions(ID_QuestionID,Question,ID_Survey)
VALUES
(1,'Question1',2),
(2,'Question2',2),
(3,'Question3',2)

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Answers
CREATE TABLE #Answers(ID_AnswerID INT,ID_Question INT,Answer VARCHAR(50),[User] INT)
INSERT INTO #Answers(ID_AnswerID,ID_Question,Answer,[User])
VALUES
(1,1,'Answer to question1',1),
(2,2,'Answer to question2',1),
(4,3,'Answer to question3',1),
(3,1,'Answer to question1',2)

DECLARE @ColList NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

;WITH TheData AS
(
SELECT
    u.[User]
    ,q.Question
    ,a.Answer
    FROM
     #Answers a
     JOIN #Questions q ON q.ID_QuestionID = a.ID_Question
     JOIN #Users u ON u.ID_User = a.[User]
)
,Questions AS
(
SELECT Question FROM TheData GROUP BY Question
)

SELECT 
@ColList = 
STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(Questions.Question),',') 
FROM
Questions


SELECT @SQL = 
'
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT
    u.[User]
    ,q.Question
    ,a.Answer
    FROM
     #Answers a
     JOIN #Questions q ON q.ID_QuestionID = a.ID_Question
     JOIN #Users u ON u.ID_User = a.[User]
) AS TheData
PIVOT (
    MAX([Answer])
    FOR [Question]
    IN (
    '+@ColList+'
    )
) AS PivotTable
'
EXECUTE sp_Executesql @SQL, N'@ColList NVARCHAR(MAX)',@ColList=@ColList
```